# python PIL and tkinter

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

Ok, so I got a new project from school, and I need to have GUI, I've used Tkinter in the past (I have very basic knowledge tho). I want to have an Image as a background, now I've been doing some research and every site basically says to use the `from PIL import ImageTk,Image` or something by those lines.
I tried it and apparently PIL is not supported by python 3.4.2, wich is what I'm using. Now here are my questions(along with other questions I have):

1. Which module replaced PIL?
2. Is there a way to use .jpg on tkinter or I'm just allowed to use .gif?
3. Is there a way to set an .svg(vector "image") as a button?

here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.font
import Image
```

the shell tells me there's no module called image

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Which module replaced PIL?

Perhaps you're referring to [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.8.1), a fork of PIL which has been more recently maintained. The module name is the same, though, so all your code should be identical. `import PIL` will still work.

> 2. Is there a way to use .jpg on tkinter or I'm just allowed to use .gif?

Yes, use `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm, in particular the section starting with "If you need to work with other file formats..."

> 3. Is there a way to set an .svg(vector "image") as a button?

Sure, if `ImageTk.PhotoImage` can handle svgs.

> the shell tells me there's no module called image

You want `from PIL import Image`, not just `import Image`.

Comment: PIL should still work? apparently my python doesn't want it lol, because when I try to import PIL it displays the error 'ImportError: No module named 'PIL'' (after posting this reply I thought it looks like I am replying sarcastically with the question at the beginning , I am not being sarcastic)

Comment: Just checking: did you install it first?

Comment: I tried, but then again It displays an error. As of what I read, it should be in the python default libraries. But then again, I probably used the wrong command(as usual), how do I install it?